# How to invert sum of matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Given are two matrices:

$\bf A, \bf B$

We know that matrices $\bf A \neq \bf B$ are invertable, symmetric, positive-definite and of full rank. Is it possible to give the formula for following sum of these matrices:

$[\bf A + \lambda\bf B]^{-1} = ?$

where $\lambda$ is a scalar such as $0 < \lambda < 1$.

Comment: It is possible for $A$ and $B$ to be invertible without $A+\lambda B$ being so. For instance take $A=B$ and $\lambda =-1$.

Comment: OK, I've edited the question

Comment: Still the same problem, you could have $B=-\frac{1}{\lambda}A$.

Comment: Have you seen the [Binomial Inverse Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_inverse_theorem)?

Comment: @JohnMoeller Type the link inbetween ( ) instead of [ ].

Comment: Ok, let's assume that $A + \lambda B$ is invertible. If it's not, then it's irrelevant anyway.

Comment: @GitGud Thanks for the tip!

Comment: In fact, if $A$ is positive-definite, $-1\frac{1}{\lambda}A$ isn't positive-definite. Maybe the contiditions on $\lambda$ are enough.

Comment: The space of positive definite matrices is convex. So $A + \lambda B$ is invertible for $\lambda > 0$.

Comment: yeah, i just realize this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming that $A+\lambda B$ is *also* invertible, you can use the [Binomial Inverse Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_inverse_theorem):

$[A+\lambda B]^{-1} = A^{-1}-\lambda A^{-1}(I + \lambda BA^{-1})^{-1}BA^{-1}$

Answer (score 3):

Use [Woodbury matrix identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity):

$$
\left(A+UCV \right)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}U \left(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U \right)^{-1} VA^{-1}.
$$