# Inverting a sum of matrices reusing known inverses

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra

Is there any way to more efficiently/elegantly calculate the inverse of $I +s A$ where $A$ is a invertible matrix, $s\in\mathbb{R}$ using a known inverse $(I + s_0 A)^{-1}$?

One idea a had was using $s = s_0 + \Delta s$ which for small enough $\Delta s$ could be [approximated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318870/how-to-invert-sum-of-matrices) as $$(\underbrace{I + s_0 A}_C + \underbrace{\Delta s A}_D)^{-1} \approx C^{-1} - C^{-1} D C^{-1}$$
in the sense of $D$ beeing a pertubation of $C$.
But what if the $\Delta s$ is not sufficiently small, is there some way to reuse the known inverse or in general calculate/approximate the inverse of $I + s A$?

Comment: I suspect looking into the Taylor series for $(I-A)^{-1}$ <https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989960/inverse-matrices-and-infinite-series> will provide some insight

Comment: As long as $||(s-s_0)A|| < \frac{1}{||(I+s_0A)^{-1}||}$ we know from functional analysis (Neumann series) that $(I+sA)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty ((I+s_0A)^{-1}(s-s_0)A)^n (I+s_0A)^{-1}$. But to be honest this is just a quick idea and i don't know if taking the first few elements of this series expansion gives a good numerical approximation...